# Meaning of data stream vector of mutually uncorrelated zero-mean symbols?

Tags: random-variables, variance, covariance, means

In my research work, I came across the following sentence:

$s \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$ is the data stream vector consists of mutually uncorrelated zero-mean symbols, with $\mathbb{E}[s s^*] = I_n$, where $I_n$ is Identity matrix.

My query is if $n = 2$, then how will the vector $s$ look like.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that $s = \begin{bmatrix} s_1 \\ s_2 \\ \vdots \\ s_n \end{bmatrix}$, and:

1. $\mathbb{E}(s_i) = 0$ (zero mean)
2. $\mathbb{E}(s_i \bar{s_j}) = 0$ for $i \neq j$ (uncorrelated)
3. $\mathbb{E}(s_i \bar{s_i}) = \mathbb{E}(|s_i|^2) = 1$

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for your detailed comment. And if I want to generate it in MATLAB then I will have to make use of standard Normal (Gaussian) random variables as it has zero mean and unit variance. Is my understanding correct sir?

Comment: You can use any distribution you like, but independent standard normal draws will satisfy these conditions, yes.

Comment: Once again thanks sir for clearing the doubt.....